# Updating old (read: pre-Java8) posts with new answers?

Tags: discussion, flags

Posted today was a question concerning [throwing exceptions on numeric overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987422/throw-exception-on-numeric-overflow).
 Before Java 8, the solutions to checking for an overflow prior to the arithmetic were a bit obtuse, as noted by [this SO post from June 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo).

On today's post there is an answer using a method from Java 8. Would it be appropriate to have that solution posted on the older thread?

Another user flagged [today's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987422/throw-exception-on-numeric-overflow) as a duplicate, citing the 2010 solutions. If that flag was accepted, I would expect [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) to be updated with a 'modern' answer(s).

**Edit:** As pointed out to me in the comments, the 2010 post does indeed have a Java 8 answer. Additionally, the accepted answer on the duplicate has since been updated to include the Java 8 solution.

Comment: There already is an answer with the Java 8 solution on the older question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26350973/3179759

Comment: @Alex, I missed that one. 

hmm.. I suppose that answers my question, thanks!

Comment: @Alex, the problem is that no one is going to scroll half way down the page to find the answer. Maybe the top answer could be updated with a section on Java 8 ?

Comment: Good point @Jonas. The top answerer is still active so I added a comment with that request. Already have +1'd the current Java8 answer.

Comment: @Jonas Top answer has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex noted in a comment above, the 2010 post *was* updated in 2014 with the Java 8 solution.

That would be the answer to my question then.. **yes** old posts <s>may</s> should be updated to include more 'modern' answers.

Comment: Yes, absolutely add new modern answers to old posts. Someone searching five years from now is not going to want to click through a whole page of search results to find which question suits them. Better to have all the answers on one page.